# How can i incorporate Expo components in a non-expo React Native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'd like to use Expo's barcode scanner component in a non-expo app that i've already mostly built:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner.html

Is it reasonable to do this? Or is it more reasonable to create a new Expo app then migrate my existing codebase into the new expo app?

My existing app was created using react-ignite, not sure if that is relevant or does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, integrating Expo components with native dependencies (such as the camera) into a non-Expo app is possible, but is a bit tricky, as you'd have to lift the source code from the Expo codebase into your application.

The JavaScript code for these modules exists in the [expo/expo-sdk](https://github.com/expo/expo-sdk) module, and are quite straightforward:

- [CameraBasedBarCodeScanner](https://github.com/expo/expo-sdk/blob/42061ce69f18012c4bda2e226f9152f8f6f5c659/src/CameraBasedBarCodeScanner.js)
- [Camera](https://github.com/expo/expo-sdk/blob/42061ce69f18012c4bda2e226f9152f8f6f5c659/src/Camera.js)

However, the [native module](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/2a4739f6224919ec4e913d45cc7c2448747ebb18/ios/Exponent/Versioned/Core/Api/Components/Camera/EXCameraManager.m) that's required to make the Camera work are embedded within the [expo/expo](https://github.com/expo/expo) client application, and depends on other parts of the Expo codebase.

Instead, I recommend you use the [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) component, which supports barcode scanning out of the box, and is easier to integrate into a plan React Native application.